# Element 'block', attribute 'class': 'about-us' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'blockClassType'

Tags: theme, magento2.2.4, data-migration

I migrated M1 data to M2 using ubertheme data migration pro.  When I install a theme to my site and load the home page, I am getting the following exception:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block',
>   attribute 'class': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'about-us' is not
>   accepted by the pattern '[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*(\[A-Z][_a-zA-Z\d]*)*'.
>   Line: 710

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a blank space

`<block class=" test\test\Block\Adminhtml\Datacheck" name='dataimprortblock' template="test::dataimport.phtml"/>`

class name was having blank space before start

" test\test\Block\Adminhtml\Datacheck"

After removing the blank space the class name

"test\test\Block\Adminhtml\Datacheck"

That fixed in my case

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can go through below link for solution:

[How to fixElement block,attribute,class](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5371)

if you find this answer helpful please mark it as solution or upvote thanks.

Comment: Hi Shubham, can you please help me locate this file; where I need to go make the change?

Comment: I am not sure still can you check "Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException"  and  "magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php"
these two files because they are basically use to validate the files.

Comment: "Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException" has nothing other than 'namespace Magento\Framework\Config\Dom;

/**
 * @api
 */
class ValidationException extends \InvalidArgumentException
{
}'

What should I look for inside "magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php" in particular?

Answer (score 0):

This error showed up to me when I created a custom block. The class attribute value was correct, there was no space or slash at the beginning, but the error was still happening.

After a lot of time, I finally figured out my module namespace was not following Magento pattern.

Apparently, [the first letter for Magento modules / namespaces must be uppercase](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173922/when-writing-modules-why-do-company-names-have-to-start-with-a-capital), or some weird errors start happening (as was my case).

So I changed my custom module from `vendor/Module` to `Vendor/Module` and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a slash issue in xml file.

```
<block class="World/Just/Block/Adminhtml/Testing" name='dataimprortblock' template="World_Just::just.phtml"/>
```

After change slash in the class name

**"World\Just\Block\Adminhtml\Testing"**

After That fixed.